# Existence of certain Analytic functions on the open unit disc ( possible application of Schwarz lemma )

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open unit disc. Then can there be analytic functions with the property

(1) $f(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{3}{4}$ and $f'(\frac{2}{3})=3/4$

2) $f(\frac{3}{4})= -\frac{3}{4}$ and $f'(\frac{3}{4})=\frac{3}{4}$

3) $f(\frac{1}{2})=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f'(\frac{1}{4})=1$

(each option should be read as separate question)

given that $|f(z)|$ $\le 1.$

Comment: Pre- and postcompose $f$ with suitable Möbius transformations to get new functions $\tilde f$ from the disc to itself satisfying $\tilde f(0) = 0$. Then use Schwarz' lemma on the $\tilde f$:s.